# type parameters of LabeledGraph in Rascal

Tags: rascal

Consider the following:

```
rascal>import analysis::graphs::LabeledGraph;
ok
rascal>LGraph[str,str,str] lg = {<"1","2","3">};
LGraph[str,str]: {<"1","2","3">}
```

Why are there only 2 type parameters to LGraph listed on the last line?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `LGraph` is

```
alias LGraph[&T,&L] = rel[&T from, &L label, &T to];
```

Since it only takes two type parameters -- one for the node type and one for the label type -- it's just disregarding the third parameter given in the declaration of `lg`.

Comment: we should have flagged an error. I guess the type checker does that right?